# d3.js v5 enter update not inserting rectangle div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js v5 version and trying to understand enter, update. I have two data set [1,2,3.5]   and other [1,2,3,4,5] . Firstly I am calling first data which renders [1,2,3.5 ] in red color and then second data is called with blue color[1,2,3,4,5] .

On update why 3 is not getting inserted in blue?

```js
              var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,5]).range([0,200]);
            
            
              var svg = d3.select("body")
                          .append("svg")
                          .attr("width",250)
                          .attr("height",250);
            
            function render(data,color){
                 // Bind data
                 var rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data);
                 
                 //Enter 
                 
                rects =  rects.enter().append("rect");
                
                //update
                rects.attr("x", scale)
                .attr("y",50)
                .attr("width",20)
                .attr("height",20)
                .attr("fill",color);
            };
             
            render([1,2,3.5],"red");
            render([1,2,3,4,5],"blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are re-assigning `rects` to `rects.enter()`. Initially `rects` contains "updated" rectangles. What you want is to get both "enter" and "update", which can be done with `merge`.

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,5]).range([0,200]);
            
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",250)
            .attr("height",250);

function render(data,color){
    // update
    var rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data, d => d);

    // enter 
    rects
      .enter().append("rect")
      // enter + update
      .merge(rects)
        .attr("x", scale)
        .attr("y",50)
        .attr("width",20)
        .attr("height",20)
        .attr("fill",color);
};

render([1,2,3.5],"red");
render([1,2,3,4,5],"blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: By default, when you call `.data(...)` d3 joins by index, so `3.5` becomes `3`. If you want to join by numerical value , so that `3`, `4` and `5` get inserted, you can pass second parameter to `.data` (read more
 https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data)

Comment: in your answer 3.5 or 3 is not shown. It should have 6 rectangles after update [1,2,3,3.5,4,5]

Comment: 3.5 is not coming even after the merge?

Comment: I modified answer, as far as I understand, you need to pass second argument to `.data()`

Comment: Looks like d3.js v3 and v4 version has some difference in the way update and enter works?

Comment: Can't say for sure. Most thorough article on selections https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/ has been written when v3 was introduced, also `key` argument to `.data()` and `.merge()` existed already in v3. So, I do not think, that there were significant changes.

Comment: My example works fine with v3 . The output is same as yours but fails in v4.

Comment: Here is your example with d3@v3, `3` still being replaced by `3.5`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/q53429011?file=index.js